# How can I use scroll view on these checkboxes

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have about 10 check boxes and I can't go up or down to see all of them. How would I use scrollview to view them here's the xml for checkboxes.

`

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

`
I want to use scroll view on this checkbox list please helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ScrollView can only contain a single View or Layout, so put your LinearLayout inside the ScrollView, then put the checkboxes inside that LinearLayout:

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
  <CheckBox />
  <CheckBox />
  <CheckBox />
  ....
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Your checkboxes need to be INSIDE the LinearLayout that's inside the Scrollview...

Comment: This answer helped me out a lot. I paired it up with the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853537/how-to-add-checkboxes-dynamically-to-an-android-layout and was able to dynamically add checkboxes for items in a list.