# Why won't this code work (Android - Scrollview)

Tags: android

When I run this app it crashes. I even tried to use LinearLayout but then it doesn't work either. What am i doing wrong guys?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: For starters, ScrollView can only accept one child.

Comment: Where is the code?  What is the error?  Post yoru LogCat and code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use scroll view on these checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938419/how-can-i-use-scroll-view-on-these-checkboxes)

Comment: @alex they woudlnt allow me to post my whole code in a comment so, I had to make another Thread.

Comment: @YusefBee You should not post code in comments, they don't have enough space and don't format it properly. You should rather edit your question and include the code in there. Click the small edit link below the tag list.

Comment: Maybe it's a copy/paste error, but you have a  `  right before the ScrollView tag... that'll throw errors and not let you build/run your app.

Comment: @Barak thats not in my app. That's how you show its code on this website.

Comment: Only sorta... that's meant for one line.. for blocks you indent four spaces (or hit the braces image at the top after you select your code text).  I've edited the question to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may only have single direct child  in ScrollView view

A scrollview can host only one direct child.

from:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

`A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through`.

so you code should be like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinerLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

 </LinerLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is log cat..........

[image]

Comment: @Deeresh I dont see any images sorry

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView only takes one View as a child.  You cannot put 3 Checkboxes in it directly.

Instead:

```
<ScrollView ... >
     <LinearLayout ...>
          <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/CheckBox13"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="CheckBox" />

          <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/CheckBox12"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="CheckBox" />

          <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/CheckBox11"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="CheckBox" />

          <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/CheckBox10"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="CheckBox" />
     </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```