# How to add CheckBoxes dynamically to an Android layout?

Tags: android, xml

I have to add CheckBox dynamically to my Activity layout, the XML of the layout is as follows
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentSV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/feedbackRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/feedbackCustomerNameLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Name : "
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/feedbackCustomerName"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/feedbackPlansLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/feedbackCustomerNameLL"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Plans Explained"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/feedbackPlansCheckBoxLL"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <!--
                        Required to Add CheckBoxes Here Dynamically
                    -->
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

CheckBoxes are to be added in the commented area. How to add them dynamically, because I have to add them in runtime based on data sent from server. I cannot remove the ScrollView or any other view from the hierarchy.

Answer (score 7):

Give that layout an `id` such as...

```
<LinearLayout   
    android:id="@+id/check_add_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feedbackPlansCheckBoxLL"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <!--
        Required to Add CheckBoxes Here Dynamically
    -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Initialize a parent layout using the given id as...

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.check_add_layout);
```

Then create your CheckBox...

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
checkBox.setId(id);
checkBox.setText("text");
```

Create parameters about its size, padding, alignment...

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
checkParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

now add this newly created `CheckBox` to the that parent layout...

```
parentLayout.addView(checkBox, checkParams);
```

Comment: This was a great succinct answer and helped me out.   I'm wondering if there is an easy way to add an click event handler now so I can know when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: @raddevus checkBox.setId(id) defines its I'd: so, all you need do is findViewById and attach onClick or onCheck Listener

Answer (score 2):

Follow following steps to add CheckBox dynamically :

**STEP 1:** Assign id to `LinearLayout` in xml to for accessing in code :

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/yourlayout"
 ....  
/>
```

**STEP 2:** access layout in code :

```
LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);
```

**STEP 3:** Add CheckBox to layout :

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for(int i=0;i<your_count;i++){

    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context); 
    checkBox.setLayoutParams(lparams); 

    linear.addView(checkBox);

}
```

Comment: I tried it but it is also giving `NullPointer Exception`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);
CheckBox chkTeamName = new CheckBox(this);
chkTeamName.setText(teamName.get(i));
chkTeamName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
layout.addView(chkTeamName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
// set the properties including layoutparams
// Then add it to parent
Parent.addView(checkBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to your LinearLayout and do

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById('your id');
Checkbox cb = new CheckBox(this);
//Give customization to it
linear.addView(cb);
```

Simple. :) Isn't it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: i did like this but i got NullPointer Exception at `linear.addView(cb);`

Comment: Did you call LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById('your id'); before adding checkbox to it? Also could you post the code where you are adding it?

Comment: And as visible from your layout, no id has been assign to the linear layout you want to add the checkbox to. So possible chances are you might be accessing something else. Do check that as well.